# Wich is the best virtual machine to run Windows 10?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-console

I'm Using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and I'm in need of using programs like solidworks and autocad for college. I hate Windows and that's why I chose the path of perpetual torment... Anyhow, which are you're your top picks for running a Windows 10 VM so that I can use such programs and alike?

Comment: Close vote since the answers will be opinion based. My opinion is virt-manager/kvm/swtpm (google the bypasschecks for RAM, ...) and Win11 23h2 installs just fine. Haven't run much on it though.

Comment: All VM applications will run Windows, as long as you provide adequate resources. "Best" is the VM application that you understand how to maintain.